# Custom python packages gives ModuleNotFoundError while importing

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-packaging

Following is my python package structure

```
pkg
|-- src
    |-- data
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- loader1.py
    |-- dataset
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- loader2.py
    |-- utils
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- chk.py
|-- setup.py
|-- __init__.py
|-- LICENSE
|-- README.md
```

After pip installation I wanted to use `from pkg.data.loader1 import func` and so I used `from pkg.data.loader1 import func` (in linux terminal). As a result, I got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named` in response.

How can I fix this.

Edit:
`setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup

with open("README.md", 'r') as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setup(
    name="pkg",
    version="0.0.1",
    description="will add",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    author="my name",
    packages=['pkg'],
    install_requires=[]
    )
```

Comment: can you include the content of your `setup.py` in your post?

Comment: and just to be sure, you did run `pip install -e .` before trying to import, right?

Comment: used ```pip3 install pkg.whl``` @Arne

Comment: these things can be tricky to debug, so I won't write an answer yet. can you first try to 1) add an empty `__init__.py` file directly under `pkg`, and 2) import `find_packages` as well, and in your `setup` call update `packages=find_packages("pkg")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have  `package_dir={"": "pkg"}`, `packages=find_packages("pkg")` and `include_package_data=True` in you `setup()` method. If not then I would recommend you to add it like this -

```
setup(
    ....
    package_dir={"": "pkg"},
    packages=find_packages("pkg"),
    include_package_data=True,
    ....
)
```

- `package_dir={"": "pkg"}` - tells ***dsutil*** packages are under ***pkg***
- `find_packages("pkg")` - include all packages under ***pkg***
- `include_package_data=True` - include everything in source control

Hopefully with this you will be able to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the structure of your import statements, what you need is probably  an additional folder holding all your sub-packages:

```
pkg
├── src  # important: its only content is pkg
│   └── pkg  # new folder here
│       ├── __init__.py  # important: this file needs to exist
│       ├── data
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   └── loader1.py
│       ├── dataset
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   └── loader2.py
│       └── utils
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── chk.py
├── setup.py
├── __init__.py
├── LICENSE
└── README.md
```

Next, your `setup.py` needs to know that `src` is the code source, *but not the package root*, which is the folder `pkg` right below it, plus all its subpackages:

```py
setup(
    ....
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    packages=find_packages("pkg"),
    ....
)
```

You can then install this package into your currently active python interpreter with `python -m pip install -e .` in a way that you don't need to re-install it after every code change (you still need to reinstall it after updating `setup.py` though).